# How to subtract the one row from another MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given that a table as enclosed

[image]

How do I find the difference between Mac and Windows sold each day. 
Can someone pls explain the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reshaping your query using an INNER JOIN on date:

```
SELECT macs_sales.Date, (MacsSold - WindowsSold) AS sales_difference
FROM
(
  SELECT Date, Sold as MacsSold
  FROM computer_sales
  WHERE Products="Mac"
) macs_sales
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Date, Sold as WindowsSold
  FROM computer_sales
  WHERE Products="Windows"
) windows_sales
ON macs_sales.Date = windows_sales.Date
```

Answer (score 2):

An INNER JOIN would do the job.

```
SELECT 
WindowsTable.Date,
ABS(WindowsTable.Sold - MacTable.Sold) absoluteDifference 
FROM
(SELECT 
*
FROM producttable
WHERE Products = 'Windows') WindowsTable

INNER JOIN 

(
SELECT 
*
FROM producttable
WHERE Products = 'Mac' ) MacTable

ON WindowsTable.Date = MacTable.Date;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c412e/1/0)

Comment: you both are correct, but since Anthony provided the answer early, I marked that as OA

Comment: If you're only interested in absoluteDifference, consider using a GROUP BY  on Date along with MAX(Sold) - MIN(Sold).

Comment: You did it right @user4943236. I've added a fiddle. You may check if required.